# How to handle Column '<ColumnName>' does not belong to table

Tags: c#, .net

i have a scenario where some `column` name of a `DataTable` may not be present. Because i am creating a dynamic `DataTable`.

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
tbl.Columns.Add("Roll");
tbl.Columns.Add("Name");
DataRow dr = tbl.NewRow();
dr["Name"] = "Arshad";
dr["Roll"] = 1;
tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
Console.WriteLine(dr["Address"]);// exception, or
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(dr["Address"]));
```

I want to check whether this `DataTable` contains a `column` called Address or not. Is it possible like we have in `Dictionary` like:

```
if (objDictionary.ContainsKey("Address"))
 {
 }
```

Comment: both are correct, but which one will work faster and why ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [DataColumnCollection.Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.contains.aspx) method as

```
if(dt.Columns.Contains("Address"))
    //column exists
```

[DataColumnCollection.Contains Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.contains.aspx)

> Checks whether the collection contains a column with the specified
>   name.